# Lifetime annotation on yielded references in for loops

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have written the following code:

```
struct Lexer<'a> {
   text: String,
   words: Vec<(usize, &'a str)>,
}

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
   fn from_str(text: String) -> Lexer<'a> {
       Lexer {
           text,
           words: Vec::new(),
       }
   }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lexer = Lexer::from_str(String::from("Mary had a little lamb"));

    for (count, word) in lexer.text.split(' ').enumerate() {
        lexer.words.push((count-1, word));
    }
    println!("{}, {:?}", lexer.text, lexer.words);
}
```

So far no problem. Then I tried to extract the for loop form the main function and put it into its own associated member function in the Lexer's implementation:

```
impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    fn lex(&mut self) {
        for (count, word) in self.text.split(' ').enumerate() {
            self.words.push((count-1, word));
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
24 | impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
25 |     fn lex(&mut self) {
   |            - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
26 |         for (count, word) in self.text.split(' ').enumerate() {
27 |             self.words.push((count-1, word));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

Now my understanding is that the `split()` and `enumerate()` functions will return string slices from `text` but in the for loop, I cannot annotate the lifetime of these references, which I then push into the `words` vector. So if I'm correct, `'1` is the lifetime of `word` and does not match `'a`, the expected lifetimes of string slices put into the `words` vector?

Why isn't it a problem when the code is not in the associated function?
What am I missing and how can I fix that?

Comment: ot: `count-1` will underflow, because the first `count` `enumerate()` gives is `0usize` which can't go below 0.

Comment: Classic self-referential struct. The fix is to store `&'a str` in the struct instead of `String`.

Comment: Might be due to type `String` outliving `&'a str`.